# How do i can animate my css effects automatically using keyframe?

Tags: html, css

**MY CSS CODE**
I get this effect from google

```
.flip-card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}



.flip-card-container:hover .flip-card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg); /* <=>  rotateY(.5turn) */
}
```

/* Position the front and back side */

```
.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* border-radius: 0.5rem; */
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #517fa4;
  color: #fff;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}



.flip-card-front img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* border-radius: 0.5rem; */
}

.flip-card-back img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* border-radius: 0.5rem; */
}
```

**DIV** I get this code from google

```
<div class = 'flip-card-container'>
        <div class="flip-card">
                <div class="flip-card-front">
                    <img src="EAT2.png" >
                </div>
                <div class="flip-card-back">
                    <img src="SAKE.png">
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

I have put my code above, sorry if im troubling you, because im new at web programming.
How do i can run this effect automatically without using hover? 
**Please help, Thank you So much**

Comment: Run it _when_? Once, when the page loads? Continuously? …?

Comment: continuosly (infinite)

Comment: Then you should probably use a CSS _animation_ instead of a transition to begin with. Those can easily be made to “loop” endlessly, whereas a transition requires that a change of the property value is triggered from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the code for your reference. I hope I understand you correctly.

```css
.flip-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-box-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: flip 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes flip {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

.flip-box-front,
.flip-box-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-box-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-box-back {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-box">
  <div class="flip-box-inner">
    <div class="flip-box-front">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/400/300/200" alt="Paris" style="width:300px;height:200px">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-box-back">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/800/300/200" alt="Paris" style="width:300px;height:200px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: glad that able to help.